# Trying to connect to MySQL server: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I want to connect to the MySQL server, but as the error suggests, my program is trying to connect to the SQL Server. How can I change that it connects to MySQL? Also I'm using NHibernate for mapping. Should this be a problem? I installed the MySQL Connector, and added as References MySQL.Data and MySql.Web but didn't changed anything.

This is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public void testMethod()
        {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.Configure();

            ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            ISession session = factory.OpenSession();
            ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

            User u = new User();
            u.Name = "AAA";
            u.Password = "BBB";

            session.Save(u);
            tx.Commit();

            session.Close();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.testMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the full stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.testMethod() in C:\Users\Stark\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 19
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Stark\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 36
```

Also, the hibernate configuration file:

```
  <session-factory name="Test">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;DataBase=assignment_4;uid=root;pwd=1234</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping assembly="ConsoleApp1" />
  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: _System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException_ notice this line? This is an exception raised by the Sql Server classes, so somewhere in your configuration you have failed to indicate the correct classes to use for MySql

Comment: "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect" and "NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" definitely don't look right if you're trying to using MySql - fairly sure the latter should be NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver

Comment: It is recommended to star (***) all credentials, You never know what You leave there.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I will keep in mind. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change details in config to use proper driver:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">
    NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
</property>
```

Some of the examples can be found here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26123/NHibernate-and-MySQL-A-simple-example

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was the fact that I followed a tutorial which connects to a SQL Server and not to MySQL. Have a good day!